# Flutter 2: Cast List<dynamic> or Map<dynamic> on what you desire

Tags: flutter, casting

I had troubles regarding my application to cast my variables into certain types.

For example:

`Map<dynamic>` into `Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>?`

How would you do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I initialise my variables:

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? test = {
    [{'test': 'test'}]
}
```

Here I want to perform a deepcopy so I use jsonEncode jsonDecode which will clone my variable and cast my clone into a `Map<dynamic>`.

```
jsonDecode(jsonEncode(test))
```

Next I want to cast my result into a `MapEntry<String, List<dynamic>>`.

```
(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(test)) as Map).map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value))
```

Finally I want to cast my value (`List<dynamic>`) into a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>? result = (jsonDecode(jsonEncode(test)) as Map).map((key, value) =>
        MapEntry(key, (value as List).map((e) => e as Map<String, dynamic>).toList())
```

Here the variable has now a type of: `Map<String, List<Map<String, dynamic>>>?`

So this is the answer for performing a deep copy with a deep casting.